# PostgreSQL: psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: postgresql

У меня есть несколько таблиц БД:

```
CREATE TABLE source_redshift.staticprompts (
    id              INT,
    projectid       BIGINT,
    scriptid        INT,
    promptnum       INT,
    prompttype      VARCHAR(20),
    inputs          VARCHAR(2000),
    attributes      VARCHAR(2000),
    text            VARCHAR(2000),
    corpuscode      VARCHAR(2000),
    comment         VARCHAR(2000),
    created         TIMESTAMP,
    modified        TIMESTAMP


);

и

CREATE TABLE target_redshift.user_input_conf (
    collect_project_id      BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    prompt_type             VARCHAR(20),
    prompt_input_desc       VARCHAR(300),
    prompt_input_name       VARCHAR(100),
    no_of_prompt_count      BIGINT,
    prompt_input_value      VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE,
    prompt_input_value_id   BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    script_id               BIGINT,
    corpuscode              VARCHAR(20),
    min_recordings          VARCHAR(2000),
    max_recordings          VARCHAR(2000),
    recordings_count        VARCHAR(2000),
    lease_duration          VARCHAR(2000),
    date_created            TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    date_updated            TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
    CONSTRAINT must_be_different UNIQUE (prompt_input_value,collect_project_id)

);
```

Мне необходимо скопировать данные из staticprompts в user_input_conf согласно условиям:

Primary Key : prompt_input_value_id

Unique Values : collect_project_id, prompt_input_value

Data Load Logic :

Insert only when new prompt input value is found for given collect project from source. Inputs column stores the values in JSON format in staticprompts table.

Insert :

Generate unique sequence number for each of the new prompt input value for a collect project id from source and store in prompt_input_value_id.

Update :

If prompt value already exists for a collect project and if there are any value changes on prompt_input_desc or prompt input name or prompt input value then update only those columns.

prompt_input_value_id - Generate unique sequence number for the combination of each prompt_input_value and collect_project_id

prompt_input_value - Inputs.value is stored in the inputs column as JSON text. Create a unique record for each inputs.value. Look at the example below this table.

Я пробую написать запрос:

```
INSERT INTO target_redshift.user_input_conf AS t (
            collect_project_id,
            prompt_type,
            prompt_input_desc,
            prompt_input_name,
            prompt_input_value,
            script_id,
            corpuscode)
        SELECT
            s.projectid,
            s.prompttype,
            s.inputs::jsonb#>>'{inputs,0,desc}' AS desc,
            s.inputs::jsonb#>>'{inputs,0,name}' AS name,
            s.inputs::jsonb#>>'{inputs,0,values}' AS values,
            s.scriptid,
            s.corpuscode
        FROM source_redshift.staticprompts AS s
        ON CONFLICT (collect_project_id, prompt_input_value)
        DO UPDATE SET
            (prompt_input_desc, prompt_input_name, prompt_input_value, date_updated) =
            (EXCLUDED.prompt_input_desc, EXCLUDED.prompt_input_name, EXCLUDED.prompt_input_value, NOW())
        WHERE t.prompt_input_desc != EXCLUDED.prompt_input_desc
            OR t.prompt_input_name != EXCLUDED.prompt_input_name
            OR t.prompt_input_value != EXCLUDED.prompt_input_value;
    """)
```

Но получаю следующую ошибку:

```
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_input_conf_collect_project_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (collect_project_id)=(1) already exists.
```

Не могу понять почему пишет, что Key (collect_project_id)=(1) already exists, если сейчас в user_input_conf пусто.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходит потому, что в `staticprompts` поле `projectid` не уникально.

Там есть дубликаты. Вам нужно решить, что с этим делать, если это нормально, то нужно убрать ограничение `UNIQUE` с поля `collect_project_id`. Судя по логике запроса у вас уникальной является пара `prompt_input_value,collect_project_id`.

Если же поле `collect_project_id` действительно уникально, то нужно решить как обрабатывать дубликаты из `staticprompts`.

Comment: Немного дополнил задачу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1321290/postgresql-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-constraint-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86